# Python error with IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, twitter

I typed this code in my Python shell command line i got an error stating "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level".

```
 from tweepy import Stream
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

    ckey='W1VPPrau42ENAWP1EnDGpQ'
    csecret='qxtY2rYNN0QT0Ndl1L4PJhHcHuWRJWlEuVnHFDRSE'
    atoken='1577208120-B8vGWIquxbmscb9xdu5AUzENv09kGAJUCddJXAO'
     asecret='tc9Or4XoOugeLPhwmCLwR4XK8oUXQHqnl10VnQpTBzdNR'

     class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status




        auth=OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
        auth.set_access_token(atoken,asecret)
        twitterStream=Stream(auth,listener())
        twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Comment: This means some indentation in your source code is incorrect. It's hard to distinguish genuinely incorrect indentation from errors introduced when copying code to this site. In your source code, is `asecret` really indented further than `atoken`? Is `class listener` also further indented? Are its method definitions `on_data` and `on_error` not indented at all?

Answer (score 2):

You have to take care of indentation when typing directly in the interpreter.  It is better to use the space bar and count (4 spaces for example) for each indentation.

I haven't run your code, but it looks like you need the indentation as follows:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = 'W1VPPrau42ENAWP1EnDGpQ'
csecret = 'qxtY2rYNN0QT0Ndl1L4PJhHcHuWRJWlEuVnHFDRSE'
atoken = '1577208120-B8vGWIquxbmscb9xdu5AUzENv09kGAJUCddJXAO'
asecret = 'tc9Or4XoOugeLPhwmCLwR4XK8oUXQHqnl10VnQpTBzdNR'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is way off.

`asecret = ...` should be unindented by a space.

Your class indentation is way off. It should look something like:

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    ...

    def on_data(self,data):
        ...

    def ...
```

If it is like this, then you could be mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that.

Comment: @VikrantCornelio You never do anything that would give an output

Comment: @VikrantCornelio I've helped you, and you said you did that. So it seems your indentation is fine

Comment: @VikrantCornelio You didn't call any of the functions, or create any instances of the class